# Adding trailing zeros in Python using the csv module

Tags: python, csv

I have values of 0 in my csv file which I would like to replace with 0.00. This way I would be able to run my script that requires float or double value (if it reads the 0 first, it will make the entire column integer when needing to be double).

This is my code thus far:

```
with open("in_file.csv","rb") as infile,open("out_file.csv","wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([f if f !=0  else '{:0.2f}'.format(0)  for f in row])
```

After this runs however, there is still no trailing zeros. Would anyone know what I am doing wrong in this situation?

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: `f != 0` might always be True  because `f` is a string ?

Comment: @Julien I have tried using f != '0' as well, but it has not been successful

Comment: Could you show a sample of your input data ?

Comment: @WillB have you tried stripping f before comparing to '0' (see answer below)?

Answer (score 0):

`f` should be a string in your code. I suspect that you have white spaces. Try this:

```
with open("in_file.csv","rb") as infile,open("out_file.csv","wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([f if f.strip() != '0'  else '{:0.2f}'.format(0)  for f in row])
```

Comment: The problem with doing the conversion here is that if there's anything in the file (in a header, say) which *can't* be converted to a float, you'll get a ValueError.

Comment: @DSM, That's correct ... I just edited my answer, so there would be no conversion. let me know if that works.

Comment: @JulienSpronck, using this snippet of code does not seem to effect the outcome of my file either. These trailing zeros are more difficult than I expected!

Comment: @WillB ok, show us your data, because this works for me\

Comment: @JulienSpronck, I am not able to show the data unfortunately but I can say that there about 20 columns and the 8th column is the most important to change by adding the trailing zeros.

Comment: @WillB It is hard to solve without seeing the data. can you put a print statement in your for loop and show us the result of `print '-'+row[8]+'-'` (or whatever index is the one for which you should change the format) for one of the lines that should be converted to `0.00`?

Comment: @JulienSpronck it returns with '-0-' for a cell which contains the value of 0.

Comment: just out of curiosity, you are sure that it is not O (uppercase o) instead of 0?

Comment: Yes, they are most certainly values of 0. That would be embarrassing!

Comment: might not solve your problem but it is simpler to do `[f if f.strip() != '0'  else '0.00'  for f in row]`

Comment: had to try :-) i'm running out of ideas

Comment: @JulienSpronck, I tried that earlier and it only works if I replace it with a legitimate value, so what I could do as a last resort is convert the value of 0 to something like .000001, which would only result in a miniscule error to the final product. I was hoping to find another way however!

Comment: i don't understand ... `[f if f.strip() != '0' else '0.00' for f in row]` is identical to this `[f if f.strip() != '0'  else '{:0.2f}'.format(0)  for f in row]`, right?

Comment: It looks like the same output to me, but I have limited knowledge with csv files and its module!

Comment: `'{:0.2f}'.format(0) == '0.00' ` ... so it is the same, independently of csv ... how do you read your output file to check that the output displays `0` and not `0.00`

Answer (score 0):

From your description; *this* is your problem:

> if it reads the 0 first, it will make the entire column integer when
>   needing to be double

When converting the string data from the CSV file, consider using the `float()` conversion function to force the conversion from string to float;

```
In [1]: float('0')
Out[1]: 0
```